# Cloudformation stack with Cloudfront deployment getting failed origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a cloud formation stack to deploy a react app from an S3 bucket. The file is below. When I go to the cloud front URL, I get the following error:

```
ERROR
Failed to contact the origin.
```

Here is the file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters: 
  ProjectSource: 
    Type: String
    Default: "https://github.com/..."
    Description: "Source control URL (e.g. Github)"
  GithubOwner:
    Type: String
    Default: (myaccount)
  GithubRepo:
    Type: String
    Default: (myrepo)
  GithubOAuthToken:
    Type: String
    Default: "(my token)"
    Description: "Github personal access token"
  GithubBranch:
    Type: String
    Default: master
    Description: "e.g. master or main"
  
Resources:
  CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipeLineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref PipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - 
          Name: Source
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Provider: GitHub
                Version: 1
              OutputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: NameForOutput
              Configuration:
                Owner: !Ref GithubOwner
                Repo: !Ref GithubRepo
                Branch: !Ref GithubBranch
                OAuthToken: !Ref GithubOAuthToken
        - 
          Name: Build
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: BuildAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: (NameHere)
              OutputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: (NameBuild)
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /service-role/
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                  - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              -
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  - "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
                Resource:
                  - "*"
  CodePipeLineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - 
                Effect: Allow  
                Action:
                  - "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds"
                  - "codebuild:StartBuild"
                Resource: "*"
  CodeBuild:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CodeBuild
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        Name: MyProject
      Source: 
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        Image: "aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.14.1"
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.1
          phases:
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
                - npm install
            build:
              commands:
                - echo Build started on `date`
                - npm run build
            post_build:
              on-failure: CONTINUE
              commands:
                - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./build s3://${DeployBucket}/
                #uncomment if you have service-worker.js 
                #- aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./build/service-worker.js s3://${DeployBucket}/
                - aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./build/index.html s3://${DeployBucket}/
                - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${Distribution} --paths /index.html /service-worker.js
          artifacts:
            files:
              - '**/*'
            base-directory: build
  PipelineBucket: 
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: {}
  DeployBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
  Distribution:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - 
            DomainName: !GetAtt DeployBucket.DomainName
            Id: !Ref DeployBucket
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: ''
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Enabled: true
        DefaultCacheBehavior: 
          MinTTL: 86400
          MaxTTL: 31536000
          ForwardedValues: 
            QueryString: true
          TargetOriginId: !Ref DeployBucket
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your S3 bucket does not have any policy to allow `Cloudfront Distribution` to access files. You need to give permission to `Cloudfront` with `CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity`.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters: 
  ProjectSource: 
    Type: String
    Default: "https://github.com/..."
    Description: "Source control URL (e.g. Github)"
  GithubOwner:
    Type: String
    Default: (myaccount)
  GithubRepo:
    Type: String
    Default: (myrepo)
  GithubOAuthToken:
    Type: String
    Default: "(my token)"
    Description: "Github personal access token"
  GithubBranch:
    Type: String
    Default: master
    Description: "e.g. master or main"
  
Resources:
  CodePipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipeLineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref PipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - 
          Name: Source
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Provider: GitHub
                Version: 1
              OutputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: NameForOutput
              Configuration:
                Owner: !Ref GithubOwner
                Repo: !Ref GithubRepo
                Branch: !Ref GithubBranch
                OAuthToken: !Ref GithubOAuthToken
        - 
          Name: Build
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: BuildAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: (NameHere)
              OutputArtifacts: 
                - 
                  Name: (NameBuild)
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuild
  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /service-role/
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                  - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt DeployBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              -
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  - "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
                Resource:
                  - "*"
  CodePipeLineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - 
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
                  - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: 
                  - !GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn
                  - !Join ['', [!GetAtt PipelineBucket.Arn, "/*"]]
              - 
                Effect: Allow  
                Action:
                  - "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds"
                  - "codebuild:StartBuild"
                Resource: "*"
  CodeBuild:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CodeBuild
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildRole.Arn
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        Name: MyProject
      Source: 
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        Image: "aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.14.1"
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.1
          phases:
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
                - npm install
            build:
              commands:
                - echo Build started on `date`
                - npm run build
            post_build:
              on-failure: CONTINUE
              commands:
                - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./build s3://${DeployBucket}/
                #uncomment if you have service-worker.js 
                #- aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./build/service-worker.js s3://${DeployBucket}/
                - aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./build/index.html s3://${DeployBucket}/
                - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${Distribution} --paths /index.html /service-worker.js
          artifacts:
            files:
              - '**/*'
            base-directory: build
  PipelineBucket: 
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: {}
  DeployBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties: {}
  Distribution:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
          - 
            DomainName: !GetAtt  DeployBucket.RegionalDomainName
            Id: !Ref DeployBucket
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Enabled: true
        DefaultCacheBehavior: 
          MinTTL: 86400
          MaxTTL: 31536000
          ForwardedValues: 
            QueryString: true
          TargetOriginId: !Ref DeployBucket
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https"

  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'CloudFront OAI'

  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref DeployBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - s3:GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Join ['', [!GetAtt  DeployBucket.Arn, '/*']]
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Still getting an access denied error. My cloud front distribution has a button allowing for the use of the website url. I'm gonna click that and see how it goes.
"This S3 bucket has static web hosting enabled. If you plan to use this distribution as a website, we recommend using the S3 website endpoint rather than the bucket endpoint."

Comment: That just brought me right back to the original error - Failed to contact the origin.

Comment: You configure your S3 bucket as static web site and want to serve it with cloudfront. 
If you want to serve your static files on S3 with cloudfront, firstly disable static web site on S3. I update changes on my answer. 

`DomainName` of S3 bucket is different if you set it as static website.

Comment: Is the only change the adding of Regional on this line - DomainName: !GetAtt  DeployBucket.RegionalDomainName?

Comment: `WebsiteConfiguration` is removed from DeployBucket as well.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I really wish the docs on this sort of stuff were clearer.

Comment: I create a simple cloudformation template with resources defined in my answer. 
Please create a new stack from [this](https://gist.github.com/gungoren/1c2aba46fd5a1b7de9bb88d4e6620f93)
Then just upload a index.html file on bucket created. 
Then only visit distribution url which is in outputs of stack.

Comment: The entire point of this stack is to automate the process of CI/CD so that I don't have to go in to the bucket and upload files.

Comment: Looking again at the individual items collected, the connection to github to pull the code is not working. It is a version 1 instead of 2 and there seem to be other issues.